# How do I handle error properly in Hapi?

Tags: node.js, rest, error-handling, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I started learning Hapi but I am unsure of error handling.

Heres my code:

```
    method: ['POST'],
    path: '/users',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        if (request.query['password'] == request.query['password_confirmation']) {
            models.User.create({
                'email': request.query['email'],
                'password': request.query['password'],
                'password_confirmation': request.query['password_confirmation'],
            })
                .catch(models.Sequelize.ValidationError, err => {
                    return reply(err);
                })
                .then(user => {
                    return reply(user);
                });
        } else {
            return reply('password do not match');
        }
```

This will generate

**Unhandled rejection Error: reply interface called twice**

How do I handle validation error properly? I can't find many

code samples about Hapi and giving me a hard time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a then block post catch

```
 models.User.create({ 
 'email':request.query['email'], 
 'password': request.query['password'],
   'password_confirmation:request.query['password_confirmation'],
}) 
.then(user => { return reply(user); })
.catch(models.Sequelize.ValidationError, err =>
{ return reply(err); })
```

Comment: oops, you are right. I was not sure of promise syntax. Thanks!